# Вывод количества символов через System.out.println

Tags: java, print

У меня есть код, который выводит две String'овские переменные через табуляцию:

```
System.out.println(dream + "\t|\t" + s_status);
```

если же я вывожу подряд два принта, выйдет что-то типа:

```
я хочу машину    |    успешно
хочу загородный дом размером с городской аквапарк    |    не успешно
```

Мне надо задавать для переменной dream фиксированную размерность, чтобы вывод был таким:

```
я хочу машину                                        |    успешно
хочу загородный дом размером с городской аквапарк    |    не успешно
```

Подскажите источники или решение. Только учу java.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение с помощью System.out.format:

```
String column1Format = "%-40.40s";
String column2Format = "%30.30s";
String formatInfo = column1Format + "\t|\t" + column2Format;

System.out.format(formatInfo, this.dream, this.s_status);
System.out.println();
```